# Reverse by Recursion

Tags: c

My code for finding reverse by recursion says **Segmentation Fault**
Why?And how to find reverse by recursion?
What is wrong with my code?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int rev(int);
main()
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    b=rev(a);
    printf("%d",b);
}
int rev(int x)
{
    int q,r;
    static int p=0;
    p=p*10+(x%10);
    r=x/10;
   q=rev(r);
    return(p);
}
```

Comment: Or at least `printf`s.

Comment: Well, for starters you have no condition to end the recursion

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions

Comment: The main problem is that you are using recursion when there is absolutely no need for it. Rewrite the recursion into a readable loop, and all your problems will go away.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `q=rev(r);` without any conditions, i.e. you jump deeper and deeper into the recursive calls, and this never ends.

In the end, you get a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function needs a way to know when the recursion ends.  This is referred to as the **base case**.  Without a base case, the recursion will keep happening until you run out of stack space, which typically causes your program to crash.

For your code, you want to get out when the argument is 0.  So you need to to this:

```
int rev(int x)
{
    int q,r;
    static int p=0;
    if (x == 0) return;    // base case
    p=p*10+(x%10);
    r=x/10;
    q=rev(r);
    return(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any breaking condition in your code in you rev() function

```
if x == 0:
       return 0
```